# Flex4 Making an ItemRender renderer with reziable drag handles

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, resize, itemrenderer

I would like to make an item renderer that can be resized by the user the idea behind that is I am making a canvas which users can layout reports on and in that I would like them to be able to rezise items.

If anyone could perhaps show me a micro sample on how to do the basics I would be very grateful.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you would need to create a List component with variable rowHeight.
This way, each row can have its own size.

Second, try using object handles for the resizing: http://www.objecthandles.com/

Cheers

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, I hope the author is willing to put up with questions, but just on principle it deserves a donation.

Very cool thank you very much.